# Flutter Web: inappwebview not returning redirected url onLoadStart

Tags: flutter, iframe, flutter-inappwebview

We are using flutter_inappwebview beta for the web. The requirement is to create a webViewWidget that can load external URLs inside the mobile & web applications. Everything works fine, on mobile but for the web `onLoadStart` is not returning the redirected URL instead it is returning the initial URL every time.

```
  InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;
  final _settings = InAppWebViewSettings(
    isInspectable: kDebugMode,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: true,
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: false,
    iframeAllow: "camera; microphone",
    iframeAllowFullscreen: false,
  );
```

Here is the build method

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final webUri = WebUri(initialUrl);
    return InAppWebView(
       initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: webUri),
       initialUserScripts: UnmodifiableListView<UserScript>([]),
       initialSettings: _settings,
       onWebViewCreated: (controller) async => _webViewController = controller,
       onLoadStart: (controller, url) async {
          // in web url value is coming as the initial uri every time. 
          debugPrint('----- Load Start: $url');
       },
     );
   }
 }
```